# python recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Update:
I forgot the quotation mark... easy fix...

I was trying to do a Leetcode question, the question is #93 **Restore IP Address**.

> Given a string containing only digits, restore it by returning all
>   possible valid IP address combinations.
>
> For example: Given "25525511135",
>
> return ["255.255.11.135", "255.255.111.35"]. (Order does not matter)

This is the correct code by using DFS:

```
class Solution(object):
    def restoreIpAddresses(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        res = []
        self.restore(s,0,[],res)
        return res
    def restore(self,s,count,path,res):
        if count == 4:
            if not s:
                temp = '.'.join(path)
                res.append(temp)
            else:
                return
        if not s:
            return
        if len(s)>2 and int(s[:3])<256 and int(s[:3])>99:
            self.restore(s[3:],count+1,path+[s[:3]],res)
        if len(s)>1 and int(s[:2])>9:
            self.restore(s[2:],count+1,path+[s[:2]],res)
        self.restore(s[1:],count+1,path+[s[:1]],res)
        return res
```

This is another approach:

```
class Solution(object):
    def restoreIpAddresses(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        res = []
        self.restore(s,0,[],res)
        return res
    def restore(self,s,count,path,res):
        if count == 4:
            if not s:
                temp = '.'.join(path)
                res.append(temp)
            else:
                return
        if not s:
            return
        if s[0] == '0':
            #self.restore(s[1:],count+1,path+[0],res)
            self.restore(s[1:],count+1,path+['0'],res)
        else:
            if len(s)>2 and int(s[:3])<256:
                self.restore(s[3:],count+1,path+[s[:3]],res)
            if len(s)>1:
                self.restore(s[2:],count+1,path+[s[:2]],res)
            self.restore(s[1:],count+1,path+[s[:1]],res)
        return res
```

The only difference is that the second approach I firstly check if `s` is start with `'0'`.
I do not understand why my second approach is wrong.
take `s = '0000'` as an example, the second approach will not write `'0.0.0.0'` to `res` even `s == ''` and `count = 4`
Please help,thanks!

Comment: Please add the problem description at the beginning of the question. I do not know how to find "Leetcode Question #93".

Comment: description is added

Comment: If you introduced well-named variables instead of inlined things like `s[:3]`, the problem would be easier to spot. Also I wonder if `return` without a value in the second `restore` is by design.

Comment: I suspect that part of this solution was suggested considering the first 18 lines of both solutions are identical. That said, I think their "solution" is terrible looking. What is a `Solution` object? What on earth is `Solution.restore()` supposed to do? What is `s` in the parameters to it? These questions are all solved by better naming.

Comment: Following @Two-BitAlchemist complaint about style... *why in the world is this even a class*? This is a procedural question, not a "Z has an X" type property modelling situation. It is very hard to find or think through solutions when you uncritically accept confused semantics (and therefore awkward tools) to solve/model a problem. What property is essential to a "Solution class of object", for example? I have no idea. Ditch the object baggage and it becomes more readable -- hence easier to identify the teeny tiny mistake hidden in there.

Comment: Yes, that is a much clearer explanation of what was underlying my 'What is a `Solution` object?' question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably with this statement:

```
if s[0] == '0':
        self.restore(s[1:],count+1,path+[0],res)
```

It strips leading zeroes. If the input is nothing but zeroes, well, then there's nothing left.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is... I forget the quotation mark...Thanks!